# Ordering Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Prove the following theorem:
Suppose $A$ is a set, $F \subseteq P (A)$, and $F \neq \varnothing.\;$ Then the least
upper bound of $F$ (in the subset partial order) is $\bigcup F.$

Comment: I take it you mean $F \ne \varnothing$ rather than $F = \varnothing$? What have you tried?

Comment: @amWhy ya, you have edited correctly, thanks.

Comment: @CliveNewstead It is F≠∅.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that for every $B\in F$ we have $B\subseteq\bigcup F$, so it is an upper bound; and if $C$ is such that for all $B\in F$ we have $B\subseteq C$ then $\bigcup F\subseteq C$.

Comment: This is the first part: Suppose ⋃F, let B be an arbitrary element of F, let x be an arbitrary element of B, then x∈⋃F by the definition of union of set. Since x is arbitrary, B⊆⋃F for all B since B is arbitrary, thus ⋃F is an upper bound of F. Is this right? I still have trouble proving it is the least upper bound. Please explain further.

Comment: @Asaf $\quad 100k\;$ "looks good" on you! Congrats (again)!

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that is correct. To prove the second part, pick $x\in\bigcup F$ and argue that it is in $C$. Recall what does it mean that $x\in\bigcup F$, and what we assume about $C$.

Comment: This is the second part of the proof, please help me to correct it if I am wrong: Let x be an arbitrary element of ⋃F. Suppose C is a set such that for all B∈F, B⊆C. Since x is an element of ⋃F, it must be an element of some B, thus x∈C. Since x is arbitrary, ⋃F⊆C.
Can you please explain how the statement ⋃F⊆C tells us that ⋃F is the least upper bound?

Comment: @Dave: The second part is correct as well. Well done. Recall the definition of a least upper bound: it is not only an upper bound, but it is smaller than any other upper bound.

Comment: So this means that ⋃F is the largest element of F, it does not contain any 'extra' element which does not present in any set of F right? Thanks for your patience and the detailed explanations!

Comment: @Dave: No, $\bigcup F$ need not be a member of $F$ itself, but it is the unique set whose elements are exactly all those elements of the sets in $F$.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks! I suppose you'll find your way to these parts of the user list soon enough.

Comment: Oh, I get it! I forgot the fact that the upper bound need of F not be the element of F. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* You need to check

- $X\subseteq \bigcup F$ for all $X\in F$,
- if $Y\in P(A)$ and $X\subseteq Y$ for all $X\in F$ then  $\bigcup F\subseteq Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of the least upper bound, first, it's an upper bound, and this is correct for $\bigcup F$ obviously. second, you should try to show that every set that includes all the members of $F$, should include $\bigcup F$.